# conflict occurred when delete one rows in my database

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

I have two table. 
tbl_User and tbl_Follow for create relationship many to many

Like a picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJEdk.jpg

I don't set Action Delete or change Roles

When i delete one row in table user sql alert error  conflict.

Comment: the reason is given of dependency of reference key in follow table. so first delete in follow table , then delete in user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the attached image there is a foreignkey realtionship between the tables tbl_User and tbl_Follow through the column id (tbl_User) and userid (tbl_Follow). For every row in tbl_Follow there is will be an entry in tbl_User with same value in columns id and userid. But it is not necessary in vice versa.

I think you are deleting a row in tbl_Users which has an entry in tbl_Follow. First delete the row in tbl_Follow then proceed to tbl_Users.

Also you can confirm the foreignkey relationship through:
Type "tbl_Follow", select the table name and press "ALT+F1" you can view a set of results where refer the resultset with columns constraint_type,name etc. There shows the foreignkey defined for the table.